# SQL Query works good if Values are False and Bad - If Null

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have simple select in SQL Server 2014

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM SignOffOperations_View 
WHERE Company = 'ASUS' AND Submission_Id = 10 AND IsOperationPerformed <> 1
```

And data in the table that can be selected if not include in where clause this: `IsOperationPerformed`

```
Id      Submission_Id Company IsOperationPerformed 
12008   10            ASUS    NULL
2527    10            ASUS    NULL
```

So, result for this query is 0. I don't get why.

Comment: `ISNULL(IsOperationPerformed,0) <> 1`

Comment: as @bummi says, you have to specifically check for NULL. Since NULL is undefined, you can't simply compare it to things. For instance, it MIGHT be equal to 1 (somehow), we just don't know, because it's NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A value of NULL indicates that the value is unknown. A value of NULL is different 
from an empty or zero value. No two null values are equal. Comparisons between 
two null values, or between a NULL and any other value, return unknown because the 
value of each NULL is unknown.

Null values generally indicate data that is unknown, not applicable, or that the data 
will be added later. For example, a customer's middle initial may not be known at the 
 time the customer places an order.[Source-msdn]
```

Use query

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM SignOffOperations_View 
WHERE Company = 'ASUS' AND Submission_Id = 10 
AND IsOperationPerformed IS NOT NULL
AND IsOperationPerformed <> 1
```

OR

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM SignOffOperations_View 
WHERE Company = 'ASUS' AND Submission_Id = 10 AND ISNULL(IsOperationPerformed,-1) <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)[Total Count]
FROM SignOffOperations_View 
WHERE Company = 'ASUS' AND Submission_Id = 10 
AND IsOperationPerformed IS NOT NULL
AND ISNULL(IsOperationPerformed,0) <> 1
```